# Concatenating strings inside file.write() in Python?

Tags: python, file, concatenation

I am trying to write a script in Python 2.7.3 that can take a .csv file from an Excel spreadsheet and convert it to a format suitable for a LaTeX table.  So I want to read a file, and write the data to a new text file, but with any commas replaced with ampersands, and a double backslash appended to the end of each line.

Example:
Input

```
A1,A2,A3  
B1,B2,B3  
C1,C2,C3
```

Desired Output

```
A1 & A2 & A3 \\
B1 & B2 & B3 \\
C1 & C2 & C3 \\
```

Here's what I have right now:

```
old_file = open(selected_file, "r")
new_file = open("texified_" + selected_file.replace("csv","txt"), "w")
#Creates new file with format texified_selected_file.txt

for line in old_file:
    new_file.write(line.replace(",", " & ") + r" \\")

new_file.close()
old_file.close()
```

Right now it properly replaces the commas with the ampersand but doesn't add the double backslash.  I thought this was because the backslash has special meaning, but even when making it a raw string it still doesn't work.  It does add it to the end of the final line, however.

Actual Output

```
A1 & A2 & A3   
B1 & B2 & B3  
C1 & C2 & C3 \\
```

Comment: If I just do `print(line.replace(",", " & ") + r" \\")`, then I only get the final line printing.

Comment: On my system the actual output is different from yours, given the example input.

Comment: @moooeeeep.. On my system too. I'm having 2 backslashes on the front of the first two lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whats wrong with your code (or with your input data), but I'd probably do it similar to this (probably less verbose):

```
for line in old_file:
    line = line.strip()     # remove newline/whitespace from begin and end of line
    line = line.split(',')  # get comma-separated values
    line = " & ".join(line) # make it ampersand-separated values
    line += r" \\"          # add latex line break
    line += "\n"            # add file line break
    new_file.write(line)
```

Or this way:

```
import jinja2

# define the latex template
template_str = r"""
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
%{ for line in table %} %{{line[0]%}} & %{{line[1]%}} & %{{line[2]%}} \\ 
%{ endfor %}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

"""

# initialize the rendering engine
renderer = jinja2.Environment(
  block_start_string = '%{',
  block_end_string = '%}',
  variable_start_string = '%{{',
  variable_end_string = '%}}'
)
template = renderer.from_string(template_str)

# bring the data array into shape
lines = [line.strip().split(',') for line in old_file]

# generate the tex source code
with open("test.tex", 'w+') as f:
  f.write(template.render(table=lines))
```

Also have a look at these resources:

- Python [csv-module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for reading csv files
- [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) for template rendering
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40728/10704 for a great example

Comment: This was really helpful.  I think I got in over my head a bit.  I'm pretty new to Python, and I saw the opportunity to put it to use.  I thought the .csv files could be treated just as .txt files, but I guess I was wrong.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is happening probably because there is a `newline` already at the end of each line in your file, and not at the end of the `last line`.

You can try stripping it, before appending the `//`, and then add the newline separately: -

```
import os
ls = os.linesep

for line in old_file:
    new_file.write(line.replace(",", " & ").rstrip() + r' \\ ' + ls)
```

Comment: I tried this code, and it had the same result, only have the backslashes on the last line.  Also tried storing the result of `line.replace(",", " & ").rstrip() + r' \\' + ls` to a variable and using that in `new_file.write()` with the same happening.

Comment: @Peacemaker636. Are you only having backslashes once? That too at the end of the last line? An no where on the first two lines? Because this is working in my case.

Comment: Yes, only once in the file, at the end of the last line.  I just tried it using the sample data in a .txt file and it worked.  But when I try it on a .csv file exported from Excel it doesn't work.